# how to prevent a checkbox to be selected using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am showing a form to the user with few checkboxes. Some of them will be pre-selected and some won't be.

like below:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="9"> nine
<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="10"> ten
<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="11"> eleven
<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="12" checked> twelve
```

Please note that in the last checkbox the `checked` keyword is added using a scriplet.

Now, even when I physically deselect check `twelve`, my javascript code doesn't understand that the checkbox is no longer selected.

*Update* 
I pasted the wrong link earlier. Here is the updated jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/JLSUK/20/

What I'm trying to accomplish alert the user ONLY when they have selected checkbox  `twelve`. However, even if that checkbox is not selected, I'm getting an alert that it IS selected. I think this is because I have `checked` in the actual HTML content, however, I can't remove that since the first time the page loads, I have to show to the user that they had this particular checkbox selected.

Is this doable with jQuery?

Comment: are you _really_ using jQuery 1.2.6, as you selected in the fiddle?

Comment: in your demo, you wanna see if any one of theses checkbox's are selected ?

Comment: What question are you asking? How to prevent the checkbox from being selected? or How to know when it is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jsfiddle you have:

```
$('#update').click(function () {
```

Whereas your `input` is:

```
<input type="submit" id="something" value="update" />
```

​Try changing your jquery to:

```
$('#something').click(function () {
```

The `#*` selector in jQuery is referring to the `id`, not the `value`.

---

Also you have:

```
if (jQuery.inArray('8', selected) >= 0 && jQuery.inArray('11', selected) >=0)
```

None of your checkboxes have a value of `8` so this will never be "true".

---

Also declare the array as a new array:

```
var selected = new Array();
```

---

[**SEE WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/JLSUK/10/)

Select "eight" and "eleven" and your popup will appear

---

**EDIT:** After seeing question edit, you need to add the following line to clear the previous array items:

```
var selected = [];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JLSUK/20/

Comment: yeah, it does, but it suggests a lack of familiarity with what's considered current best practise...

Comment: @Alnitak Do you have any source for this information? I'm not questioning you, but would like some evidence before I change my methods.

Comment: what u think of that ? http://jsfiddle.net/JLSUK/14/ made one not using a array, i dont know if is realy this what he needs

Comment: It was in one of Crockford's videos - I forget which.

Comment: @RicardoArruda I won't dispute whether there is a way of achieving the same results without an array. One could simply check whether a checkbox with a value of `8` and a checkbox with a value of `11` are selected. But your example does not do this.

Comment: @Curt yes, if is this what he need, main dont do that, i was just asking the best way on doing this, check in a array or making a loop. No dispute :)

Comment: @RicardoArruda This is probably the way I'd do it http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/JLSUK/17/

Comment: I forgot to update the jsfiddle before posting the question: This is the correct link I meant to paste http://jsfiddle.net/JLSUK/18/

Comment: will just initializing the array in that way work? I believe I'll have to remove items from the array as the checkboxes are changed..

Comment: @Mike Each time the `update` button is clicked a new instance of an array is created, which will therefore be empty. So you don't need to clear any arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding elements to the array, but you are never removing them.  So every time the user clicks 'update', you are simply filling your array.  At some point you either need to clear the array, or remove the previous selection from it (depending on your exact logic).

Comment: This would work! Let me see how I can remove elements from the array